# modal still pops up even if other button is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When i click on the edit button my modal for editing information pops up but when I close it out and click the button for adding an entry the edit modal still pops up. Any ideas?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">

                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a medicine</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modal_form_id" method="POST">
                                               <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label mb-10">Generic Name</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="medicine_id" id="medicine_id">
                                                    @foreach($items as $item)
                                                    <option value="{{$item->id}}" >{{$item->generic_name}}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group" id="form-group-dosage_name">
                                                <label class="control-label mb-10">Dosage Volume</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="dosage_name" id="dosage-volume" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: 20mg">
                                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group" id="form-group-form">
                                                <label class="control-label mb-10">Form</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="form" id="form-dosage" class="form-control" placeholder="Bottle, Tablet">
                                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group" id="form-group-price">
                                                <label class="control-label mb-10">Price Per piece</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
                                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group" id="form-group-photo">
                                                <label class="control-label mb-10">Insert a photo</label>
                                                <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                     <div class="mt-20">
                                                        <input type="file" name="photo" id="input-file-now" class="dropify" >
                                                    </div>  
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" id="save-dosage">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

so that's the code for the modal

Comment: We need to see some code really. One possible cause could be you have the same modal target set on each button.

Comment: Sounds like invalid HTML, have it validated. In addition, show it to us so we can dive deeper into the problem.

Comment: basically its named id of myModal.

Comment: Can you provide brief mark up your code? I doubt if you don't have same IDs or other same selectors for both the buttons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this happened because of the ID's name being conflicted or redundant either in these both case.

**First**, wrong target(Noticed `data-target="#myModal"`) :

```
// --------------------------------- Here
<button type="button" data-target="#myModalAdd" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" >
 Open Modal
</button>
// --------------------------------- Here
<button type="button" data-target="#myModalEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" >
 Open Modal
</button>
```

All you need to do is, make sure the `data-target` property target correct modal box(Modal box can be differentiate by using id, eg : `<div id="myModalAdd" .....>`

**Second**, you're calling directly/programmatically from js code like so :

```
$( '#myModalAdd' ).modal('show'); // or
$( '#myModalEdit' ).modal('show');
```

Make sure `$( <modal's ID> )` the selector is correct in this case.

Comment: Yeah that would be much better if I just separate my modals

Comment: Of course, separate it for readability and maintenance in future. After all, its depends on the use case